# How to convert png image into autocad format in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am converting png image into autocad format(.dxf).But after conversion png to dxf .Image is not opening in autocad software.

### Code for convert PNG image into DXF format

def download_dxf

```
data = open("#{Rails.root}/public/result.png").read
send_data data, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename=>"map.dxf",type: "application/CAD",content_type: 'application/CAD',mime_type: 'application/CAD'
```

end

Inside public folder result.png image is existing from where i am picking this image and convert them into DXF format.[image]

After conversion image is not opening in autocad software.

Comment: Have you tried a 3rd party service like https://convertio.co/png-dxf/ ? They have an API I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a real programming problem, but a file format problem. I'd say that you must learn a lot about how file formats work before addressing this kind of issues. You can't convert from a file format to another by simply opening it and sending the same data it to another file. Additionally, *png* is a raster image format while *dxf* is a vector format, which means that converting one thing to the other is not a trivial problem.

And, specifically over the code, I don't know how to program in Python, but I'd say that you can't use *send_data* to write data to a file.